# How to apply a function across two columns in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I am writing a function to find if two columns satisfy a condition, and if so, I want to return a new column with a statement. I thought I could just do df.apply(function), but it does not seem to work!

```
def bucketing(df):
    if df['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' and df['CTRY_OF_RESIDENCE'] == 'Russia':
        return 'High Risk'

merged.apply(bucketing, axis = 1)
```

This is my error:

```
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for |: 'str' and 'str'
```

My expected output would be a new column with the string 'High Risk' returned if the above condition is met.

Is there a more efficient way of doing this?

Thanks

Comment: Please explain better what are you trying to do. Post your dataframe and your expected output

Comment: Thanks, essentially my expected output would be a new column with the string 'High Risk' returned if the above condition is met like in my statement.

Answer (score 1):

Here is an easier way:

```
import numpy as np
df['new col'] = np.where((df['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU') & (df['CTRY_OF_RESIDENCE'] == 'Russia'), 'High Risk', np.where((df['NATIONALITY'] == 'UK') & (df['CTRY_OF_RESIDENCE'] == 'Ukraine'), 'Medium Risk', ''))
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the error it returns: ValueError: The truth value of a Series is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all().

Comment: I have corrected the answer

Comment: Thanks very much this is awesome! Am I able to create multiple rules in this one where statement? for example, a second saying if df['Nationality'] != 'RU' and df['CTRY_of_Residence'] == 'RUSSIA'), 'Medium Risk').

Comment: Sure. You can run it as many times as you like

Comment: Is it possible to merge it within the same statement, so the one column which is returned, returns either High Risk or Medium Risk?

Comment: I have updated my answer

Answer (score 0):

If you want to still utilize your code I think this would work but a sample DF would help to check

```
def bucketing(row):
    if row['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU' & row['CTRY_OF_RESIDENCE'] == 'Russia':
        return 'High Risk'
df['NEW COLUMN'] = df.apply(bucketing, axis=1)
```

Comment: Thanks, this is the error I receive: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for &: 'str' and 'str'

Comment: Would be good to get a short part of the DF for me to understand why you get that.

Answer (score 0):

I would use a np.where() to get you what you are looking for

```
data = {'Name' : ['John Smith', 'Jane Doe'],
        'NATIONALITY':  ['RU', 'NA'],
        'CTRY_OF_RESIDENCE': ['Russia', 'America']
        }

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
df['new col'] = np.where((df['NATIONALITY'] == 'RU') & (df['CTRY_OF_RESIDENCE'] == 'Russia'), 'High Risk', '')
df
```